# How to get __r.id related fields from Trigger.new?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am unable to get the value from below contact. How we can get the related field data ?

```
trigger NIGO_update on NIGOs__c(before insert, before update) {
    for ( NIGOs__c ng : Trigger.new ) {
        NIGOs__c nigo = Trigger.newMap.get(ng.Id);
        if ( ng.Product_Type__c != 'Forecare' && ng.Contact_Name__c != null ) {
            /*** here I am getting a null value ***/
            ng.External_Wholesaler__c = ng.Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__r.Id;
        }
        System.debug('Ext1' + ng.External_Wholesaler__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to run a query for these items. They won't be contained in trigger.new. They're related objects, not fields that are contained in the object your trigger is fired on. You'll need to collect the Ids and construct a query to obtain them, then operate on the results.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the ids out of the `Trigger.newMap.keySet()` and query for the newly inserted `NIGOs__c` with the related fields, then proceed with your logic as before.

```
trigger NIGO_update on NIGOs__c(before insert, before update) {

    Set<Id> nigoIds = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
    List<NIGOs__c> nigos = [
        SELECT 
        Product_Type__c,        
        Contact_Name__c,
        External_Wholesaler__c,
        Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__r.Id
        FROM NIGOs__c
        WHERE Id IN :nigoIds
    ];

    for ( NIGOs__c ng : nigos ) {
        NIGOs__c nigo = Trigger.newMap.get(ng.Id);
        if ( ng.Product_Type__c != 'Forecare' && ng.Contact_Name__c != null ) {
            /*** here I am getting a null value ***/
            ng.External_Wholesaler__c = 
            ng.Contact_Name__r.Annuity_Territory_Wholesaler__r.Id;
        }
        System.debug('Ext1' + ng.External_Wholesaler__c);
    }
}
```